# Json data to excel , pdf and csv with own design format in java

Tags: java, excel, pdf

I want to generate a report in excel and pdf with designed format in java. like header font and style , column size and all settings to be in java to generate excel in own format.

Comment: You can't order people to get things done for you. Have you tried something

Comment: It's nice that you want that. What is stopping you from actually getting it?

Comment: @user7 ... i have done with dynamicreports, apache POI and jExcel. but i am expecting some other smart way to design dynamically. dynamic design of report is hard to achieve.

Comment: Still, it's not clear what you want to achieve and what do you mean by dynamic? Please update the question with more details to help get more response

Answer (score 0):

to generate excel document you need libs like [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

to generate pdf and even html libs like [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) may help you.